# How can I get an update on an old question?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

How can I get an update on an old question?  For instance, [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/165178/internet-history-eraser).  I'd like to hope that there have been updates in the software available to someone with this question.

I guess my real question is, how do I ask for an update to a question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we take care of our old duplicates?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3524/how-can-we-take-care-of-our-old-duplicates)

Comment: I think this is a very real problem. I'm not sure this is enough of a duplicate to warrant closing, but it can't hurt to bring more attention to slhck's topic.

Comment: @DanielBeck The fact that nobody mentioned placing bounties on old topics is actually quite interesting. It's definitely a way of getting **new** information for old questions. Otherwise, I like the idea of writing a new community-FAQ question and closing the old one as a duplicate. But that doesn't work for all kinds of questions

Comment: The browers built-in cache cleaner suffices well enough. If you run multiple browsers or you want to remove caches and history among your computer then tools like CCleaner and ATF Cleaner still do a nice job...

Comment: @TomWijsman Is this really a comment on this topic?

Comment: @DanielBeck: It is the only way to reach wizlog. Check the link...

Comment: @TomWijsman You should follow that up with an answer to this question and suggest to just *mention the question on Meta* :-)

Comment: @DanielBeck: No, because it is a comment. Not an anwer...

Answer (score 5):

You can place a bounty on the question asking for more and additional information.

Comment: What if its not really worth 50 REP?

Comment: @wizlog Then there is no way. If you want an answer desperately enough to be updated, then it's worth the reputation.

Comment: well then we (SuperUser) should create a way.

Comment: @wizlog Why? Come up with something but in the close on 2 years that SE has been in existence this has never been a requirement.