# What should be done about questions whose answers go obsolete?

Tags: discussion

https://superuser.com/questions/75228/most-efficient-desktop-cpu-in-terms-of-gflops-watt is an example, but there are many more. Any answer given, while it may be accurate at the time, will not be in a year.

Should we allow such questions?

Comment: close as too localized.

Comment: Even if it is current? (now that is, and therefore applies to a large number of people)

Comment: First sentence of Too Localized mentions "this question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors;" which fits this bill.

Comment: But it will help visitors for the next month or more, just not after a year.

Answer (score 2):

Are there such recent examples? Most such newer questions should/will be closed as Too Localized. As for the older ones, time to cast your close & delete votes.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/369072/what-is-the-best-liquid-for-a-liquid-cooling-system is recent.

Comment: @soandos What you've posted is a different matter. Types of cooling liquid won't change as much as CPU specs.

Comment: @slhck, I have no idea how quickly new types of coolent come out, but I am not sure that we should set a time horizon (good for one year keep it, good for six months, ditch it) type of rule.

Comment: @soandos That's going to be hard. This is exactly why we have community voting, and I think it works pretty well. The time horizon really depends on the case.. It wouldn't have made sense to close the early SSD questions just because they are outdated *now*, but it does not make sense to keep questions about *the fastest XYZ on the market*.

Comment: @slhck, unless there is a process for going back to these questions in a years time, they will just stick around...

Comment: @soandos Of course. Then it's time to create a new question and close the old one as a duplicate of that. See [How can we take care of our old duplicates?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3524/48078)